# Screen "dies" whenever "ls" is executed

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, ls

I'm running Screen 4.00.03 on my RHEL 5 server. Wheneven I open a new screen and execute `ls` the screen dies. This only happens in this server and not in other servers. What is causing this problem?

ETA: I should add that I also have a Nvidia GPU installed on this server, but I'm not sure how/if this affects anything because I'm accessing it remotely using ssh.

Comment: How does the screen die - does it report any error? What is its `$?`? Does it happen in any directory? What does `ls` output in a non-screen session? Are there any files with non-ascii characters in their names? What happens if you run screen locally, `ssh` to the server from it and run `ls`?

Answer (score 1):

I might be because of a corrupt /bin/ls or your ls is pointing to some other file. You can check if the ls on this server is the same as others.

Comment: My ls is in the same directory, but it's a slightly bigger and newer file (91240 bytes, Feb 23, 2010 on this server vs 89816 bytes, Nov 28, 2006 on the other servers)

Comment: If the servers are otherwise the same, with the same distro and same versions of the base system, this difference is a Very Bad Thing. Sounds like it might be time for a security audit, and some additions to your CRLs.